# How do I run a command on all files from git ls-files?

Tags: git, bash, shell

We have a CI script that does style checking on all Python files in the repository like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find . -name \*.py -exec pep8 --ignore=E402 --max-line-length=120 {} +
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    >&2 echo "=== PEP8 errors need to be solved ==="
else
    echo "=== PEP8 check ok ==="
fi
pytest
```

However, there are a few things that are either not checked in, or `.gitignore`ed. So I would like to take the output of `git ls-files` and run the command only on those. I could loop but I don't want to make assumptions about the developer's chosen shell. Ideally, I would like to filter `find`s output via set difference with `git ls-files`.

Comment: Pipe to `xargs`? `git ls-files | xargs foo`…

Comment: The `pep8` tool can take directory names on the command line and supports the `--exclude` and `--filename` options to provide patterns to include and exclude.  In many cases, this is enough to select the files you want to check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git ls-files -z \*.py | xargs -0 pep8 --ignore=E402 --max-line-length=120
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    >&2 echo "=== PEP8 errors need to be solved ==="
else
    echo "=== PEP8 check ok ==="
fi
pytest
```

Should do you.

`git ls-files -z` and `xargs -0` allow spaces in file names etc

from the `xargs` man

> `-0, --null`
>                 Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special  (every  character is taken literally).  Disables the end of file string, which is treated like any other argument.  Useful when input items might contain white space, quote marks, or backslashes.  The GNU find `-print0`  option
>                 produces input suitable for this mode.

from the `git ls-files` man

> `-z`
>              \0 line termination on output.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want only specific file extensions

I was surprised because I had an insane amount of line of codes, turn out that it was because of .png files and other files that don't mean much.

In case you are looking for only certain extensions (in my case dart, py and c), *kindly find the following script for your convenience*:

```
git ls-files | grep -e "\.\(dart\|py\|c\)$" | xargs wc -l
```

So basically if for example java is your main extension file (/trigger all the java haters and lovers) you put java inside the escape sequence:

```
git ls-files | grep -e "\.\(java\)$" | xargs wc -l
```

(copy/paste and replace java with your current main file extension)

And then add:

```
\|file_extension
```

Right after the first extension (in this case after the 'a' from java) for each subsequent file extension that you also want to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to run a command on all files in a repo with a file suffix (extension) is:

```
git ls-files -z '*.py' | xargs -0 pep8 --ignore=E402 --max-line-length=120
```