# How do I add a large amount of files from a folder onto github using git bash?

Tags: git, github

I have over 6000 image files that I need to push to a github repository (into 6 individual folders). However I can only upload 100 folders at a time, and I'd rather not just drag and drop for an hour. Is there a way to use git bash to deposit 1000 files at a time into the github folders? I've already cloned the repository into a local machine, so I just need to find a way to add over a 1000 files at once into the folder directory, and then commit and push. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `git add folder[1-6]`

Comment: What does the [1-6] do?

Comment: It is a wildcard and expands to `folder1 folder2 folder3 .... folder6` (if they exist). You could also just run it manually `git add first_folder second_folder folder3 folder-four ....`

Comment: Do I need to specify the folder path? or just the name of the file?

Comment: Passing a path to a directory will add all files and subdirectories of this directory. Passing a path to a file will only add this single file.

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding what you're saying. Don't I want to add all the files that are in the folder? 

So I have my path open to the folder I want to push the files to. 

Then I do: 

git add C:/path/folder_with_all_images.

But it won't let me add them and It's saying that it's outside the repository.

Comment: You can only add/commit files that are part of your working tree. You cannot add files outside of your repository. If you want to add/commit something, it must be part of the working tree. If it is not already, you have to copy it. This has nothing to do with the amount of files, this is Git basics.

Comment: @topsail I have an external file(s) full of images from Kaggle. I need to push them to github, but i'd like to do it all at once. However there are over 6000 images.

Answer (score 1):

You can add only the first n files, as [illustrated here](https://git%20ls-files%20--others%20--exclude-standard%20%7C%20head%20-n%20100%20%7C%20xargs%20git%20add), using [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) (listing untracked, not ignored files):

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | head -n 1000 | xargs -0 git add
```

You can see more at "[How do I run a command on all files from git ls-files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41085442/6309)"

Answer (score 1):

As written in your question, you already cloned the repository on your machine. Let's assume the repo is cloned into `C:/path/to/repo`. This means that the content of this folder is a representation of the content of your repository.

To add the files, you first need to copy them into this folder or a subfolder thereof. For example, you can place them in `C:/path/to/repo/folder1`, `C:/path/to/repo/folder2`, ...

Afterwards, add them to the index with [*git-add*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add), e.g. with `git add folder1`, `git add folder2`, ...

Then you can commit the changes (in this case all the new files that are were added to the index) with [*git-commit*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), e.g. `git commit -m "Add 6000 images"`.

Finally, you can push with [*git-push*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), e.g. `git push`.